# 2 out of 3 or 5 out of 8

Tags: probability

If given a chance to score football goal freekicks, which should be chosen: $2$ out of $3$ kicks or $5$ out of $8$ kicks.

My thoughts: $2$ out of $3$, since probability of winning would be $\dfrac{2}{3} \approx 0.66$
But in case of $5$ out of $8$, probability would be $\dfrac{5}{8} \approx 0.62$.

I'm not sure if I'm correct.

What if the choice is between $2$ out of $3$ and $4$ out of $6$.

Comment: What exactly are you choosing here?  If you score 2 out of 3 kicks you have +2.

Comment: It depends. Do you want a higher number of goals or a higher ratio of goals to missed shots?

Comment: given the two choices which one should you pick to have greater probability of winning.

Comment: If all you care about is probability, then go with $\dfrac{2}{3}$. Like you said, the probability of scoring is higher.

Comment: But if the choice is between 2 out of 3 and 4 out of 6, then it shouldn't matter since probability is same in both case, right?

Comment: @user3344591 exactly.

Comment: Why are we not doing probability=(2 goals out of 3 + 3 goals out of 3) ?

Answer (score 3):

We assume (unrealistically) that on any kick we have a certain fixed probability $p$ of succeeding, and that success/failure on the various attempts are independent.

The probability of at least $2$ out of $3$ is $A$, where 
$$A=3p^2(1-p)+p^3.$$

The probability of at least $5$ out of $8$ is
$B$, where 
$$B=56p^5(1-p)^3+28p^6(1-p)^2+8p^7(1-p)+ p^8.$$
We want to find out for what values of $p$ we have $A\ge B$. There is a little cancellation, but solving the inequality *exactly* may not be feasible.

Intuitively, if we are very a poor kicker (but don't always miss!), then $A\gt B$. If we are a good kicker, then $B$ is better. For numerical details, one could ask Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I literally just computed this calculation! Great answer! I will get there first next time. +1

Comment: Wolfram alpha says to go for the 2 out of 3 if you are less than $\sim 26\%$ likely to score on any one goal. For exact solutions, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3p2%281%E2%88%92p%29%2Bp3+%3E56p5%281%E2%88%92p%293%2B28p6%281%E2%88%92p%292%2B8p7%281%E2%88%92p%29%2Bp8.

Comment: Thank you. That there would be a "transition" probability  was clear, but I had not tried to locate it numerically.